# Inventory Item Implementation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the moment I have an inventory implementation that works like this
- There is a *base class called `Item`* which is what the inventory array contains, then there are *classes `Weapon` and `Consumable` which inherit from `Item`* and then *class `Gun` which inherits from `Weapon`*. But, I have a problem I want items to have changeable properties meaning, i want the `Gun` class to hold the amount of ammo in the Gun but if it is changed then considering it is using the same instance of the class then it will change the ammunition for all of the specific type of gun that is in the inventory. I have heard of `ICloneable` but it is apparently depreciated and shouldn't be used.

My items script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Items : MonoBehaviour
{
    static Dictionary<int, Item> items = new Dictionary<int, Item>();

    private static bool initialized;

    [SerializeField]
    Texture2D[] itemIcons;

    private void Start()
    {
        Gun desertEagle = new Gun();
        desertEagle.damage = 40;
        desertEagle.range = 20;
        desertEagle.maxAmmunition = 7;
        desertEagle.firemode = FireMode.Semi;
        desertEagle.firerate = 1;

        desertEagle.name = "Desert Eagle";
        desertEagle.description = "Desert Eagle (.50 Cal) is a semi-automatic pistol with an ammo capacity of 7 rounds";
        desertEagle.equippable = true;
        desertEagle.icon = itemIcons[1];

        Consumable donut = new Consumable();
        donut.food = 30;

        donut.name = "Donut";
        donut.description = "A ring full of legendary awesomeness";
        donut.equippable = true;
        donut.icon = itemIcons[2];

        Consumable coffee = new Consumable();
        coffee.water = 30;
        coffee.stamina = 50;

        coffee.name = "Coffee";
        coffee.description = "A delicious beverage to help you get up in the morning. Goes well with donuts.";
        coffee.equippable = true;
        coffee.icon = itemIcons[3];

        RegisterItem(1, desertEagle);
        RegisterItem(2, donut);
        RegisterItem(3, coffee);

        initialized = true;
    }

    public static void RegisterItem(int id, Item item)
    {
        items.Add(id, item);
    }

    public static void UnregisterItem(int id)
    {
        items.Remove(id);
    }

    public static Item GetItem(int id)
    {
        return items[id];
    }
}

public class ItemStack
{

    Item item;
    int amount;
    int max = 10;

    public void Add(int amount)
    {
        if (item.stackable && this.amount + amount <= max) this.amount += amount;
        else if (item.stackable) this.amount = max;
    }

    public void Remove(int amount)
    {
        if (item.stackable) this.amount -= amount;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string name = "Item";
    public string description = "Your everyday standard item.";
    public bool equippable = false;
    public bool stackable = true;
    public Mesh model;
    public Texture2D icon;
}

public class Weapon : Item
{
    public float damage = 5;
    public float range = 1;
}

public class Gun : Weapon
{
    public int ammunition = 1;
    public int maxAmmunition = 1;
    public FireMode firemode = FireMode.Semi;
    public int firerate = 1;
    public new float range = 10;
}

public enum FireMode
{
    Semi,
    Automatic,
    Burst
}

public class Consumable : Item
{
    public float food;
    public float water;
    public float health;
    public float stamina;
}using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

My inventory code:

```
Item[] inventory;

[SerializeField]
int inventorySize = 16;

inventory = new Item[inventorySize];
inventory[0] = Items.GetItem(1);
inventory[1] = Items.GetItem(2);
inventory[12] = Items.GetItem(3);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand what you want. Just as a side note, you may consider making your `Consumable` an interface (like `IConsumable`) , the name suggests it. Then you could have classes like `Coffee` and `Donut` implementing it.

Comment: Don't know if I understood your problem. Do you want to have shared ammunition? If you have 2 desert eagles they share the ammunition you have. That's it? If that's it, you just have to use your ammunition as consumables.

Comment: Basically if the values of one item is change because the same instance of the item is used as the ones stored in the item list the value for all of that item in the inventory changes

Comment: I think I found out the problem and two ways to fix it. Posted an answer already. If it is not what you was looking for please let me know. And if it is, please accept the answer.

Comment: ComputerFido please let me know if my answer resolved your question and accept it if it have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Json & Type Approach**

So as i commented before, it is possible to use json and Type to create the dictionary and clone the registered objects. I have changed your code to do that. See below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;//Included to use Type and [Serializable]

public class Items : MonoBehaviour
{
    public struct SerializedObject //struct to hold the type of the object and the json string
    {
        public Type type;
        public string json;
    }

    static Dictionary<int, SerializedObject> items = new Dictionary<int, SerializedObject>();//dictionary must hold both type and json string to be used with JsonUtility

    private static bool initialized;

    [SerializeField]
    Texture2D[] itemIcons;

    private void Start()
    {
        Gun desertEagle = new Gun();
        desertEagle.damage = 40;
        desertEagle.range = 20;
        desertEagle.maxAmmunition = 7;
        desertEagle.firemode = FireMode.Semi;
        desertEagle.firerate = 1;

        desertEagle.name = "Desert Eagle";
        desertEagle.description = "Desert Eagle (.50 Cal) is a semi-automatic pistol with an ammo capacity of 7 rounds";
        desertEagle.equippable = true;
        desertEagle.icon = itemIcons[1];


        Consumable donut = new Consumable();
        donut.food = 30;

        donut.name = "Donut";
        donut.description = "A ring full of legendary awesomeness";
        donut.equippable = true;
        donut.icon = itemIcons[2];

        Consumable coffee = new Consumable();
        coffee.water = 30;
        coffee.stamina = 50;

        coffee.name = "Coffee";
        coffee.description = "A delicious beverage to help you get up in the morning. Goes well with donuts.";
        coffee.equippable = true;
        coffee.icon = itemIcons[3];

        //For each object store the Type and serialize the data using JsonUtility
        SerializedObject so_desertEagle;
        so_desertEagle.type = desertEagle.GetType();
        so_desertEagle.json = JsonUtility.ToJson(desertEagle);
        SerializedObject so_donut;
        so_donut.type = donut.GetType();
        so_donut.json = JsonUtility.ToJson(donut);
        SerializedObject so_coffee;
        so_coffee.type = coffee.GetType();
        so_coffee.json = JsonUtility.ToJson(coffee);
        RegisterItem(1, so_desertEagle);
        RegisterItem(2, so_donut);
        RegisterItem(3, so_coffee);

        /*//Made this for testing 
        Item gunCopy = GetItem(1);
        Gun desertEagle2 = (Gun) gunCopy;
        desertEagle2.ammunition--;

        Debug.Log(desertEagle.ammunition + " / " + desertEagle2.ammunition);
        //Debug result is "1 / 0"
        */
        initialized = true;
    }

    public static void RegisterItem(int id, SerializedObject item)
    {
        items.Add(id, item);
    }

    public static void UnregisterItem(int id)
    {
        items.Remove(id);
    }



    public static Item GetItem(int id)
    {
        return (Item) JsonUtility.FromJson(items[id].json, items[id].type); //Use JsonUtility to create a copy of the serialized object
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ItemStack
{

    Item item;
    int amount;
    int max = 10;

    public void Add(int amount)
    {
        if (item.stackable && this.amount + amount <= max) this.amount += amount;
        else if (item.stackable) this.amount = max;
    }

    public void Remove(int amount)
    {
        if (item.stackable) this.amount -= amount;
    }
}

[Serializable]//JsonUtility only works with [Serializable] objects
public class Item
{
    public string name = "Item";
    public string description = "Your everyday standard item.";
    public bool equippable = false;
    public bool stackable = true;
    public Mesh model; //I would recommend storing the meshes in another dictionary and setting a reference here
    public Texture2D icon;
}

[Serializable]
public class Weapon : Item
{
    public float damage = 5;
    public float range = 1;
}

[Serializable]
public class Gun : Weapon
{
    public int ammunition = 1;
    public int maxAmmunition = 1;
    public FireMode firemode = FireMode.Semi;
    public int firerate = 1;
    public new float range = 10;
}

[Serializable]
public enum FireMode
{
    Semi,
    Automatic,
    Burst
}

[Serializable]
public class Consumable : Item
{
    public float food;
    public float water;
    public float health;
    public float stamina;
}
```

---

**Swith Case Approach**

I think I have found the problem. You should return a copy of the item in GetItem function instead of a reference to the original object in Items. You don't even need to store the originals.

Try this get function:

```
public static Item GetItem(int id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case 1:
            Gun desertEagle = new Gun();
            desertEagle.damage = 40;
            desertEagle.range = 20;
            desertEagle.maxAmmunition = 7;
            desertEagle.firemode = FireMode.Semi;
            desertEagle.firerate = 1;

            desertEagle.name = "Desert Eagle";
            desertEagle.description = "Desert Eagle (.50 Cal) is a semi-automatic pistol with an ammo capacity of 7 rounds";
            desertEagle.equippable = true;
             desertEagle.icon = itemIcons[1];
             return gun;
        case 2:
            Consumable donut = new Consumable();
            donut.food = 30;

            donut.name = "Donut";
            donut.description = "A ring full of legendary awesomeness";
            donut.equippable = true;
            donut.icon = itemIcons[2];
            return donut;
        case 3:
            Consumable coffee = new Consumable();
            coffee.water = 30;
            coffee.stamina = 50;

            coffee.name = "Coffee";
            coffee.description = "A delicious beverage to help you get up in the morning. Goes well with donuts.";
            coffee.equippable = true;
            coffee.icon = itemIcons[3];
            return coffee;
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you need to register the items in runtime I would suggest serializing them as JSON and storing the JSON and the Type. The following links might help with that:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4

Comment: I will have a look at the json thing but i dont think i will use the switch as that could get quite messy

Comment: I've added the solution with JsonUtility to the answer if you are interested. It have tested it here and it works fine. Also added some comments on the changes I've made and some suggestions in parts of your code.